# Prove a graph G is not color-critical.

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

A graph is color-critical if removing any vertex decreases its chromatic number.

Show that if $G=H_{1} \bigcup H_{2}$ is the union of two sub-graphs $H_{1}$ and $H_{2}$, neither a sub-graph of the other, whose intersection $H_{1} \bigcap H_{2}$ is a single edge, then $G$ is not color-critical.

I think I understand most of what is going on in this problem, but I am not sure how to go about showing it is true. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you tell us the part you understand of what is going on in this problem, and then we can help you from there.

Comment: @bof I’ll allow myself to answer instead of Andrew, because my first impression about the qusestion was the same as his. The second impression is that we need to impose on the graphs $H_i$ some additional conditions, because in the present  formulation any graph $G$ with at least one edge has a required cover by $H_i$’s.

Comment: @AlexRavsky That's not true if we also keep track of the vertices where $H_1$ and $H_2$ intersect.

Answer (score 1):

If we can color $H_1$ by $k$ colors and $H_2$ by $l$ colors, then we can color $G$ by $\max\{k,l\}$ colors. To do this, just relabel the coloring of $H_2$, if necessary, so that it agrees with the coloring of $H_1$ on the two vertices connected by the single edge where $H_1$ and $H_2$ intersect; then take the union of the two colorings.

Therefore $G$ has a subgraph (either $H_1$ or $H_2$) with the same chromatic number as $G$: if $k \ge l$, then $\chi(G)=\chi(H_1)$, and if $k \le l$, then $\chi(G)=\chi(H_2)$. So it cannot be color-critical.